# Swift adding a UICollectionView in place of the navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm attempting to add a UICollectionView to the navigation bar in place of the navigation title, as is done in the native Messages app in iOS. Here's as far as I've gotten:

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()

    var collectionview: UICollectionView!
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: navigationBar.frame.width, height: navigationBar.frame.height)

    collectionview = UICollectionView(frame: navigationBar.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionview.dataSource = self
    collectionview.delegate = self
    collectionview.register(UserImagesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "userCell")
    collectionview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionview.backgroundColor = .red

    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = ""
    navigationItem.titleView = collectionview

    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
```

This code runs without any errors, but displays nothing on the view controller. There's something I'm missing here, and I can't put my finger on it. Any help?

EDIT:
After help from Mike's answer, here is the code I landed on to create a uicollectionview inside my nav bar with a custom cell xib file.

```
func setupCustomCollectionView() {
    if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: navigationBar.frame.width / 4, height: navigationBar.frame.height)

        collectionview = UICollectionView(frame: navigationBar.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionview.dataSource = self
        collectionview.delegate = self
        let nibCell = UINib(nibName: "UserImagesCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionview.register(nibCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "userCell")

        collectionview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionview.backgroundColor = .red

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = collectionview
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to replace a title with a View "as is done in the native Messages app in iOS"? Please post a screenshot of what that means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to display the collection view using this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = collectionview
```

...instead of your last four lines of code that create a navigation item.

I noticed that because `layout.itemSize` is set to occupy the entire navigation bar, the `cellForItemAt` method was only called once, even when I specified a larger number in `numberOfItemsInSection`.

By changing the `layout.itemSize` to a smaller value, `cellForItemAt` was called more than once.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I had to modify the code a bit more for a custom collection cell with xib file. I've updated my question to include that code incase someone else needs it.